# Cannot get fgetcsv file to work with MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, fgetcsv

I have tried to get this to `fgetcsv` function to output all rows of `CSV` file into my database. It seems quite standard functionality but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code I am trying to run:

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['records_csv']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

while(($csv = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO records(artist, title, type, size, year, status)
    VALUES ('".$csv[0]."', '".$csv[1]."', '".$csv[2]."', '".$csv[3]."','".$csv[4]."','ACTIVE')"; 
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "File uploaded successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

When I do run it, it only seems to enter the second line of the file into the database? I don't know why this is happening??

My CSV file looks like this:

```
The Jam,All Around The World,Single,7 inch,1977
The Jam,Strange Town,Single,7 inch,1979
```

And my form I am uploading from looks like this:

```
<form method="post" class="AddCSV_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="records_csv">
    <input type="submit" name="csv_sub" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look hat your `while()` loop, where `$sql` is set and then look at the place where you use `$sql` in `query()`, do you see the issue with that?

Comment: Just a point on your question formatting, best avoid putting thanks and 'please help' in a question.  It helps to keep things nice and standardised on SO.

Comment: @SingleEntity - Standardised? If being polite isn't standardised then that quite bad formatting in a question in my opinion.

Comment: @HarryHawkes - your opinion is correct, and I too used to put polite comments in, only to have them removed.  It's just the way SO is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = $_FILES['records_csv']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
$values = array();
while(($csv = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
{
   $values[] = "('".$csv[0]."', '".$csv[1].
               "', '".$csv[2]."','".$csv[3]."','".$csv[4]."','ACTIVE')"; 
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO records (artist, title, type, size, year, status) VALUES "
       . implode(',',$values); 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "File(s) uploaded successfully!";
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

have a nice ...

Answer (score 0):

JUst as JustOnUnderMillions spotted out, change code to this:

```
$file = $_FILES['records_csv']['tmp_name'];
                    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

                    while(($csv = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO records
                         (artist, title, type, size, year, status)
                        VALUES ('".$csv[0]."', '".$csv[1]."', '".$csv[2]."',
                        '".$csv[3]."','".$csv[4]."','ACTIVE')"; 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "File uploaded successfully!";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    } 
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Biju P Dais I never thought of it like that :-)